# Open windows explorer from Silverlight

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, windows, silverlight

Is there a way to open Windows Explorer (a specific folder) from browser based Silverlight application? Is there a way to get the machine name in the Silverlight app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to open the Windows Explorer from your Silverlight app.

Another way is to use the [SL4 OOB (Trusted Application)](http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures) using the COM Automation functionalities.